# Placing a Reset Filter button in highcharts when a filter is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the following code in my legendItemClick: function(event). It turns the legend filtering into a 'radio button' style format, you can only view one set of data at one time. The problem is when you click a series name, it doesn't let you come back out to the view that lets you see all points.

Is there a way to place a button that says "Reset Filter", somewhere in the legend whenever a filter is enabled?

I noticed that when you zoom in using a mouse, a "reset zoom" button appears, this is what I would like, except for when a filter is enabled through the legend.

```
                                var seriesIndex = this.index;
            var series = this.chart.series;

            for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
            {
                if (series[i].index != seriesIndex)
                {
                    series[i].hide();
                } 
                else
                {
                    series[i].show();    
                }
            }
            return false;
```

I tried this code, after reading this link, http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=15416

but could not get it working, perhaps, I am placing it wrong? I put it at the end, inside the "scatter" brace, which is directly inside the plotOptions brace.

```
chart.renderer.button('Reset zoom', null, null, chart.resetZoom, {
   zIndex: 20
}).attr({
   align: 'right',
   title: 'Reset zoom level 1:1'
}).add(chart.zoomGroupButton).align({
   align: 'right',
   x: -10,
   y: 10
}, false, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra series without any data with `name: "Reset filter"`, and then in `legendItemClick` check if that series was clicked  (just compare name). So when clicked - show all series.